# convert vertical text to horizontal using paste -d or tr

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have list of data in vertical format , I want it in horizontal format

`fl.txt`:

```
data
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output required is :

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

My code :
when I am using this command it prints only last value : 5

```
 paste -s -d "" fl.txt
```

Comment: You already gave the start of the solution in the subject (`paste`  and `tr`). What else do you want? For us to read the man page for you to work out the details?

Comment: What part of this exercise do you have issues with? Removing the header, transforming the data to a single row, or getting the correct delimiter between the entries on the row?

Comment: @Kusalananda transforming data to single row

Comment: @Kusalananda i have added my code

Comment: Just leave a space between the double quotes (to define the space as the delimiter)

Comment: @Kusalananda not printing i tried to do : $ paste -s -d " " fl.txt
 5

Comment: @Kusalananda i am running this command in git bash shell

Comment: I suspect you have Windows line endings in your input file, `\r` or `^M`,so every field is overwriting the previous one. First run `dos2unix` on your input file and then  try your command.

Answer (score 3):

From comments it's clear that you're working with a file containing Windows text data.  Convert it to a Unix text file using `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix fl.txt
```

Once it's a Unix text file, you may remove the first line of the file, which contains the `Data` header, using `sed 1d fl.txt` or `tail -n +2 fl.txt`.

The resulting lines may be converted to space-delimited columns on a single line by replacing all newlines by spaces:

```bash
sed 1d fl.txt | tr '\n' ' '
```

This would, however, generate output that is not terminated by a newline character.

You may also use `paste` in a way similar to what you propose:

```bash
sed 1d fl.txt | paste -s -d ' ' -
```

The `paste` command would generate a single line terminated by a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed

```bsh
sed '1d; s/\r$//' f1.txt | paste -sd " "
```

or, implement the paste part in sed

```bsh
sed -n '1d; s/\r$//; H; ${ x; s/^\n//; s/\n/ /g; p }' f1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple option in bash or ksh93:

```
echo $(<fl.txt)
```

Or:

```
xargs -a fl.txt
```

The first lines can be removed like this:

```
{ head -1 >/dev/null; paste -sd' '; } <fl.txt
```

Or:

```
{ head -1 >/dev/null; fmt -100; } <fl.txt
```

in subshell:

```
(>/dev/null head -1; xargs) <fl.txt
```

Comment: That may work unless the data contains shell globbing characters, assuming it's a Unix text file. But it would not remove the `Data` header.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Thanks. I think this is a typo in the example